# Jruby persistence problem

Tags: ruby, persistence, jruby

I want to store objects in jruby for a short time. The objects use procs so I seem to have trouble storing it into db. If anyone has good ideas for how to persist jruby objects for 1-5 mins it would be great.

These objects are quite large, specifically, celerity browser objects.

For now, I have created a model in jruby like so:

```
class Persist
    @@persistHash ||= Hash.new

    def self.storeItem(id, item)
        @@persistHash[id.to_s] = item
    end

    def self.getItem(id)
        return @@persistHash[id.to_s]
    end
end
```

I have warbled the app and deployed it to glassfish v2.

I run the program and it works fine for a while. But after a day, if I call 'get' right after 'store' (10-20 secs) I am returned nil.

I can't find any errors in logs.

EDIT: I have also found that the item is indeed inserted into the hashtable (the hashtable did not run out of memory during insert):

Before 24 hrs:

Persist.storeItem() followed by Persist.getItem() works fine.

A http call for store. Then another http call for get returns the object.

After 24 hrs:

Persist.storeItem() followed by Persist.getItem() works fine.

A http call for store. Then another http call for get returns nil.

Comment: I wonder if your instance(s) of Persist are in a local scope that gets destroyed upon exiting that scope. Have you looked into that?

Comment: I'm not sure how to instance it properly. I assume the store and get are static class methods and I just call Persist.storeItem from a different model or controller. Even if the Persist class was being reloaded all the time, I don't understand why it would work fine for a day.

Comment: You're right - I hadn't noticed they were class methods even though I noticed the @@. My next thought was that it was getting reloaded all the time too but given that it works OK for a day, I'm perplexed. Have you tested it at 23:59 and 24:01 hours (i.e., are you sure it's at the 24 hour mark, or maybe it gets reset at 0:00?)

Comment: I'm upgrading my jruby and trying to get profilers working right now. But I just wanted to let you know I didn't mean 24 hours exactly. I just know that it works for the 8+ hours I'm at work and then breaks when I show up the next day >.>

Comment: Still does not work in jruby v 1.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the object being deleted at any point.

I would examine the JVM using other tools. It could very well be that you've exhausted memory but the log message / exception never gets created to report the memory exhaustion.

May I suggest hooking up JMX monitoring of the various heap regions and create a means by which the hash can purged of old objects.

Wish I had more for you. Good luck!

Comment: It seems to add to the hashtable properly. I will check the JMX monitors. I wonder if anybody have a better way of persisting large jruby objects that have procs? Is there any cool serialization gems out there?

Comment: There was indeed a memory leak. It was strange that nothing showed up in any logs, and that it was able to work after the set. I spammed jmap live:histo | grep 'jruby' and eventually found what I was looking for ^^.